# The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object - Angular 7

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, phantomjs

I try to run test on my angular project typing

```
ng test --browsers=PhantomJS
```

Before, I must install phantomjs manually using command

```
npm install phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16 -ignore-scripts
```

But after `ng test --br ...` I receive this error

> 23 05 2019 08:08:28.194:ERROR [config]: Error in config file!
>    TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object
>       at validateString (internal/validators.js:125:11)
>       at Object.extname (path.js:1365:5)
>       at phantomJSExePath (/gui-build/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/index.js:18:12)
>       at Object. (/gui-build/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/index.js:107:12)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)....

How can I fix this?

> ENVIRONMENT: Angular CLI: 7.3.9
>    Node: 10.15.3
>   OS: linux x64
>   Angular: 7.2.15

**karma.conf.js**

```
 // Karma configuration
 // Generated on Wed Oct 24 2018 11:15:29 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)
 const path = require('path');

 module.exports = function(config) {
 config.set({
 files: [
  'src/**/*.js',
  'src/test/**/*.js'
 ],
 basePath: '',
 frameworks: ['jasmine'],

 preprocessors: {
  '!(test)/**/*.js': 'coverage'
 },

 plugins: [
  require('karma-jasmine'),
  require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
  require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
  require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
  require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
 ],

 client: {
  clearContext: false
 },

 coverageIstanbulReporter: {
  reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary' ],
  dir: path.join(__dirname, 'coverage'),
  skipFilesWithNoCoverage: true,
  fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
 },

 angularCli: {
  environment: 'dev',
  config: '@angular/cli'
 },

 // list of files to exclude
 exclude: [
 ],

 reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'], 
 port: 9876,
 colors: true,
 logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
 autoWatch: false,
 browsers: ['Chrome'],
 singleRun: true,
 concurrency: Infinity
 })
} ;
```

**package.json**

```
{
 "name": "gui",
 "version": "0.0.0",
 "scripts": {
 "ng": "ng",
 "start": "ng serve",
 "build": "ng build",
 "release": "ng build --prod",
 "test": "ng test",
 "lint": "ng lint",
 "e2e": "ng e2e",
 "version": "git add -A package.json && git commit",
 "postversion": "rm -rf build/temp"
 },
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
 "@angular/animations": "^7.2.15",
 "@angular/common": "^7.2.15",
 "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.15",
 "@angular/core": "^7.2.15",
 "@angular/forms": "^7.2.15",
 "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
 "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.15",
 "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.15",
 "@angular/router": "^7.2.15",
 "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^3.3.0",
 "core-js": "^2.5.4",
 "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
 "intl": "^1.2.5",
 "lodash": "^4.17.11",
 "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
 "tslib": "^1.9.0",
 "zone.js": "~0.8.29"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
 "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
 "@angular/cli": "~7.3.9",
 "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.15",
 "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.15",
 "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
 "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
 "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
 "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
 "jasmine-core": "^2.99.1",
 "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
 "karma": "^1.7.1",
 "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
 "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.4",
 "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
 "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
 "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
 "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.16",
 "protractor": "~5.3.0",
 "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
 "tslint": "~5.9.1",
 "typescript": "~3.2.4"
 }
}
```

How can I fix it? Thanks in advance

Comment: [PhantomJS is discontinued](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15344). Consider using something like a [headless browser](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)

Comment: I also try  ChromeHeadless but error is same... Maybe problem with karma.conf.js ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by removing `"karma-phantomjs-launcher"` from the `karma.conf.js`

note: was able to do this, because we were not using `phantomjs`, which from my understanding has been deprecated for a little while now.

Comment: just run in the same issue. Removing "require('karma-phantomjs-launcher')," really did the trick. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 browsers: ['Chrome', 'PhantomJS'],  // HERE MISSING 'PhantonJS'
```

karma.conf.js

```
 // Karma configuration
 // Generated on Wed Oct 24 2018 11:15:29 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)
 const path = require('path');

 module.exports = function(config) {
 config.set({
 files: [
  'src/**/*.js',
  'src/test/**/*.js'
 ],
 basePath: '',
 frameworks: ['jasmine'],

 preprocessors: {
  '!(test)/**/*.js': 'coverage'
 },

 plugins: [
  require('karma-jasmine'),
  require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
  require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
  require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
  require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
 ],

 client: {
  clearContext: false
 },

 coverageIstanbulReporter: {
  reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary' ],
  dir: path.join(__dirname, 'coverage'),
  skipFilesWithNoCoverage: true,
  fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
 },

 angularCli: {
  environment: 'dev',
  config: '@angular/cli'
 },

 // list of files to exclude
 exclude: [
 ],

 reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'], 
 port: 9876,
 colors: true,
 logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
 autoWatch: false,
 browsers: ['Chrome', 'PhantomJS'],  // HERE MISSING 'PhantonJS'
 singleRun: true,
 concurrency: Infinity
 })
} ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstall karma-phantomjs-launcher and phantomjs-prebuilt, it works for me ...